# Mysql echo of fields

Tags: php, mysql

In Excel, records are entered in single rows going across, and columns.
[image]

I have a searchable online Mysql (using PHP) working database, with a single table to query same which so far is working great. All my online input queries work great, except for one which eludes me to date:

I would like to Query & ECHO results of each Company related information ONCE, followed by each person that works within each Company - then, next Company data again followed by all employees within it, Etc... all in one query without repeating the Company information again which is redundant.

I have been tried my best to research the above for a few weeks before asking for your help. I would appreciate any guidance you may be able to offer me related to this task - Thank you in advance for your time and guidance !

Comment: Can you add some more information about how your database is structured and what you've tried so far?

Comment: My database table mirrors the Excel Sheet above. For trials, I use Sequel Pro to query the database using a variety of multiple queries. I have tried the usual  SELECT DISTINCT FROM WHERE GROUP combinations with no success. Again, my objective is to ECHO Company, Address, City State, Zip - ONCE - followed by First-Name, Last_Name, Title for all employees that work within that Company without having to repeat all the redundant company information again. Then, I would continue to ECHO all the rest of the records  in similar fashion until all rows were finished. - Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution: Do a `SELECT DISTINCT` on your "station" field. This will return you a set of all unique stations.([read about distinct selections here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp))

Put that data into an array called `$uniqueStations` or something.

Then you can use a `foreach` loop to go through each value in `$uniqueStations` and echo out employee data with a different `SELECT` based on the unique station. ([More on foreach here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))

Comment: Your answer and idea seems logical and extremely simple. I will try this and let you know how it works out - Thank you very much !!!!

Comment: Being a neophyte myself, and in the interest of helping others, I am including a simple short video url to "How to Use ARRAYS". https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06bDOtzsuh8

Comment: Why treat PHP like a database when the database calls can do this, a ton faster.